# Display different result if didn't find the ID in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, toggle

I have a select menu and some divs associates with it. I want the select menu to hide / show divs according to the select menu value. But if the jQuery didn't find the associative div then it should alert some text.

Here is my code:

```js
$('select').change(function(){
  var div = $(this).val();
  $('#results div').hide();
  $('#' + div).show();
});
```

```css
#results div {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option value="div_1">Div 1</option>
  <option value="div_2">Div 2</option> 
  <option value="div_3">Div 3</option> 
</select>

<div id="results">
  <div id="div_1">Div 1</div>
  <div id="div_2">Div 2</div>
</div>
```

As you can see in my example above there is no `DIV 3` so I want an alert saying that there is no `DIV 3` found.

Any kind of help appreciated :)

Comment: You can check to see if the `.length` of the jQuery object is zero. That indicates that the selector matched no elements.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `length` of a jQuery object to check for matches

```
$('select').change(function() {
      var $div = $('#' + $(this).val()).show();
      if ($div.length) {
        $('#results div').not($div).hide();            
      } else {
        alert('No Match')
      }      
});
```

Personally I think this is a bad user experience and a better approach would be to remove or disable `<option>`s that don't have matches.

```
$('option').filter(function(){
    return !$('#' + this.value).length;
}).remove()// or prop('disabled', true);
```

Comment: Why did you use `.not ()`?

Comment: don't want to hide the correct target .. right? I used show() when defining that target

Comment: and you used $div variable with a `$` sign... Can you explain a bit about that? 

Comment: just a convention that many people use to know that that variable is already a jQuery object

Comment: Means if write it like `var my_string` or ` var $my_string` it doesn't matter? both will work same way?

Comment: It didn't work :(
Its not showing the appropriate div... Just keep alerting

Comment: works fine here https://jsfiddle.net/Lq3qvst3/. Note that other answer searches dom multiple times for same element

Comment: Yes I can see its working but when you select `DIV 3` it still shows the last selected div. Results should be cleared and then alert.

Comment: Simple change... however note that was never specified and is not what you stated in previous comment

Comment: Ok I have made it work by adding `$('#results div').hide();` in `else` ... Thanks .... Can you tell me how it is accessing DOM multiple times?

Comment: Inefficient to search more than once for the same thing when you can cache one instance

Comment: Thanks Charlie ☺ that's explained everything

Answer (score 1):

check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s7g2nxhg/)

```
$('select').change(function(){
     var div = $(this).val();
     $('#results div').hide();
    if($('#results').find('#' + div).length > 0){
      $('#' + div).show();
    } else{
      alert("not find")
    }
});
```